# C. basics. exiting a loop

Tags: arrays, c, loops

I'm looking for a way to exit a loop from the user side.
I'm working on a code that should fill an array until the array is filled completely or until the user decides that he is done. I tried to cook something with an `if` statement inside the loop but it didn't pay out, did something wrong.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 6
void main() {
    printf("enter numbers sorted by their value, from low to high.\n");
    int HT7Q1[SIZE], kelet=0, kelettot=0, num2=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        scanf("%d",&kelet);
        HT7Q1[i] = kelet;
```

I'm trying to creating a key word or a letter that when is used by the user the loop would be terminated at that point. wasn't successful so far and would like some help.
thank you.

Comment: The `break` keyword allows you to exit a loop.

Comment: "a key word or a letter" If you only allow integers in your `scanf` call you cannot detect keywords or letters. You could only check if `scanf` returns 0 indicating that it was not an integer.

Comment: can i have a char type variable that will be ignored until it is used by the user?

Comment: You could replace your `scanf` with `fgets` to read a string. Then check for your keyword and if it is not found, use `sscanf` to get the integer from the string.

Comment: for example lets say i have: ```scanf("%c",char);``` but the code is unread until a char type character is used. is something like that possible?

Answer (score 0):

If the user enters some invalid characters (like "quit" or whatever) you can break the loop.

```c
if (scanf("%d",&kelet) != 1) // Break if an invalid conversion happened
   break;
```

Comment: but then I'm not allowing the user to use that number. im working with an arranged, i thing the term, array. it can contain bot negative and positive numbers in it as long as the numbers are arranged.

Comment: I updated the answer, so the user can enter some non numeric text to quit.